# Uploading a file to S3 from Node and Express backend

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I'm following a [tutorial](http://blog.pragmasoft.com.tr/how-to-upload-image-binary-etc-data-directly-to-amazon-s3/) on how to upload an image file onto an S3 bucket. However, no file shows up in the designated S3 bucket. As described in the tutorial, I send a  "putobject" request to get a "signed url" as a response.

```
s3bucket.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function(err, data){
    // Error...
    else{
        var return_data = { requestUrl: data };
        res.json( generalResponse( return_data ));
    }
```

I then pass the return_data variable to an instance of **XMLHttpRequest**
to make a put request.

```
xhr.open("PUT", signed_request);
```

The configuration of CORS in both Express and S3 are shown below:

**Express:**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});
```

**S3 Bucket:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

There is no syntax error or server error that appear in neither nodeman shell or console. I'm thinking that there must be some configuration problem that's preventing the file being uploaded into S3 from client-side. 
I would really appreciate your help on this issue.

Comment: A couple of sanity checks: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/backupbarry/?region=eu-west-1&tab=properties

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

Comment: Maybe, taking a look at its code, or trying it, this [high level nodejs  s3 client](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client) could help you.